# Word for "someone with no responsibilities assigned to them"?

Tags: single-word-requests

### Concept

What is the word for someone who has no responsibility? I am meaning a situation where someone lacks anything to be responsible for.

Adjusting Google/Oxfords' meaning of "responsibility" to try and make the concept more clear:
The state or fact of having **no** duty to deal with **anything** or of having **no** control over **anyone**.

Specifically, I am looking for an adjective that describes a person. Like responsibility, it should reflect one's duty or state, not one's desire. But unlike responsibility, it should not imply a moral obligation nor a lack thereof.

---

### Example Usage

Example sentences using a phrase:

- "The baby, previously lacking anything to be responsible for, finally set their heart on locomotion: the art of flailing limbs and sliding belly to move across the plush carpet.
- "His body finally able to rest, the industrial man becomes the man that now lacks anything to be responsible for."

With a made up word "aresponsible":

- "The once aresponsible baby finally set their heart on locomotion: the art of flailing limbs and sliding belly to move across the plush carpet."
- "His body finally able to rest, the industrial man becomes the aresponsible man."

---

### Antonyms Tried

While checking Cambridge's Thesaurus for antonyms "be responsible for" gave no results, "be responsible" only gave the word "innocent". Innocent seems to mean a lack of knowledge or a state of being wrongfully accused. Innocent does not convey my idea properly. A lack of responsibilities can be known or not known and has nothing to do with accusations.

Another common suggestion is "irresponsible", from wiktionary.org's antonym list for example, but it comes with the assumption that responsibility is being neglected or there is a lack of ability to handle responsibility. Someone without responsibility could very well be aware and capable of it, but not have any and may never be obligated, expected, or assigned any in the future. This does not mean they are an irresponsible person.

---

I will try to source to the best of my ability:

([Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/responsible#English) 8/13/2021)

(Original Google/Oxfords' [definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=responsibility) of responsibility, *"The state or fact of having a duty to deal with something or of having control over someone."* 8/13/2021)

Comment: This lack doesn't surprise me, as people are generally weak on the subject of responsibility and often conflate the term with "culpable."

Comment: Wiktionary and some other online sources have "dutiless" or "dutyless" but it doesn't seem to have made it into the dictionaries I consulted. Nonetheless, the meaning is fairly obvious (although it could refer to tariffs in another context).

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a single English word that accurately conveys the state of both an infant and an active retiree.

Comment: 1: *spoon fed*, 2: either *empty nester* or *deceased*. There's no single word, but there's a joke about walking on four legs, two legs, and then three legs. How about: Anti-social? Republican? Enlightened? Preadolescent? Trust-fund baby? My personal favorite is IDGAF.

Comment: Probably not what you asked, but in business context (especially software development) IC (individual contributor) is often used for non-leads/managers. (Of course everybody has responsibilities there)

Comment: If one were to consider a responsibility a burden, you could label this person as "Unencumbered".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**carefree**

> ADJECTIVE
> Free from anxiety or responsibility.
> *‘the carefree days of summer’* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/carefree)

**carefreeness**

> The trait of being without worry or responsibility [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/carefreeness)

> But for most of us **carefree** living is taking no responsibilities and
> an escape from the world itself. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Heart_2_Heart/MFteDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=carefree%20responsibilities&pg=PT35&printsec=frontcover).

> Childhood is idealized as a **carefree** period—no responsibilities, no
> worries about calories. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Kids_These_Days/UQRvAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=carefree%20responsibilities&pg=PA41&printsec=frontcover).

> She had been eighteen, no age at all really, but though they had both
> been delighted at the thought of parenthood, **carefreeness** had flown
> out the window. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Such_Sweet_Sorrow/9ZfrwxX-V5oC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=carefreeness&pg=PA88&printsec=frontcover).

You could refer to a *carefree state/existence,* or the *state/condition of being carefree* if that works better than *carefreeness.*

Comment: I had never heard the word *carefreeness* before, and it produced zero results on Ngram.

Comment: I saw a [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=carefreeness&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccarefreeness%3B%2Cc0) there when I tried it just now, and it's in *The New Oxford American Dictionary* under *carefree*

Comment: Bizarre; I just searched, and it came back with zero. Wonder if there was just a server glitch.

Comment: And you think “carefreeness” is English usage?

Comment: @David Are you asking me?  The OP was looking for an adjective, and in suggesting one, I pointed out that it also has a noun form. I also found it awkward, which is why I suggested alternatives if the OP does as well and needs a noun. As for usage, I didn't put it in an Oxford dictionary -- ask them.

Comment: I would suggest this word doesn't automatically imply what the OP wants. In life, it's impossible to not have some responsibility, so the word is a necessarily subjective. As long as you have easy responsibilities, people still think of it as "carefree living". And I would be confused if you wrote a sentence like "I have three carefree employees you can borrow". Not saying it's a terrible choice, or that I have a better answer, just that it's not perfect and the OP should take care with its use.

Comment: @MichaelS. If someone says I have three carefree employees you can borrow, they are most likely using *carefree* in the other sense  in the definition: *free from anxiety*.  You can often find examples where a given word won't work or another of its meanings comes into play; yours is an example. The OP didn't provide a fill-in-the-blank example of intended usage.

Comment: Yes, but unlike, say "employed" as meaning "I have a steady job" (sometimes it's just a temp job), I don't think most people would instantly think of "carefree" meaning "no responsibilities at all" so much as "nothing of major consequence" or "nothing stressful". The example given in the OP with the baby is similar to my example, except my example makes more sense with this word. In my experience, "carefree" means a lack of worry, not a lack of required duties. Those can be synonymous, but it's common for them to not be, so extra care should be taken.

Comment: The problem lies with *job* or *employment*-- you have a job *as a waiter*. You are employed *as a bank clerk or teacher*. *Job* entails responsibilities in its definition. So a *job without any responsibilities* may be the only way to express this exactly. A *carefree job* might span both meanings. I'd like one.

Answer (score 11):

For completeness, a very specific term in government is: minister **without portfolio**.

Most government ministers have responsibility for a government ministry or department or other office (known as their ‘portfolio’).  But a politician can be given a ministerial salary and participation in cabinet meetings and decisions without that specific responsibility, by appointing them [minister without portfolio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minister_without_portfolio).  This may be because they hold a non-government position (such as party chairman), or have an area of responsibility not aligned with the existing structures, or simply because the head of government values their participation at that level.

Comment: And while we're adding related words, there's **sinecure**: a job position with no responsibilities (or only trivial ones) that still gets full benefits. More general than "minister without portfolio", still not applicable to the baby in the example. (Although now I'm imagining some embittered soul describing a baby's existence as a sinecure...)

Comment: “without portfolio” was my first thought from the question title, but reading the question body, it doesn’t seem to fit the asker’s intention at all.

Comment: It would appear that you posted your answer first. If so I didn’t see it when posting mine. I’ve withdrawn it.

Comment: "Baby without portfolio" is a good phrase.

Comment: This is not common US usage

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Naturally not—the US government doesn’t have *ministers*. What’s the term in the US for an advisor or other official who works in the executive branch, but doesn’t have a specific role like Secretary of Department X? …“president’s son-in-law”?

Comment: @TimPederick There are "[senior] advisors to the president," but it doesn't have the same connotations, and you can't call a baby a "senior advisor to the president" to imply they're without responsibilities.

Answer (score 5):

I'd go for "footloose". It literally means "unshackled", but - according to Etymonline.com - it has meant "free to act as one pleases" since 1873.

If that feels a bit informal, you might try "unengaged". It can mean "currently without a job", though (on the downside) it could also suggest "detached" in a disparaging sense.

Yes, it's interesting, isn't it? I kept feeling that the answer to your question was obvious, that it was on the tip of my tongue; but nothing really satisfying ever arrived. It definitely feels like we *should* have a word for it, but even a word like "insouciant", which literally means what you're asking for, has taken on that rather dismissive feeling, as if to describe someone as being "without responsibilities" is a criticism.

Answer (score 3):

**Floater**

As in, somebody within an organization who does not have a fixed assignment. Rather, their skills are deployed as and where they are needed (e.g. paraprofessional aides who move between classrooms).

Comment: Alternatively (and similar to @gidds answer of "without portfolio"), one could use the qualifier "at large." For instance,  many professional bodies have an elected position called "member at large"."

Answer (score 2):

Unaccountable
2.
(of a person, organization, or institution) not required or expected to justify actions or decisions; not responsible for results or consequences.

"there are enormous risks in leaving such agencies uncontrolled and unaccountable"

(definition from Google)

Unburdened, Unencumbered or unfettered first came to mind, but I feel like these words imply a being released from some obligation.

Thank you for the interesting question!

Comment: I'm not sure that "unaccountable" works here. There are many company bosses who have plenty of responsiblity but who are accountable to no one but themselves.

Comment: @KillingTime: It's an oddity of English. "Responsible", "accountable", "answerable" all *ought* to mean the same thing: "required to respond/account/answer to [an authority]". But "responsibility" (and not the others) can be used for things you're "supposed" to do even if no-one's checking on you. Having a duty to *oneself* (as you say), or maybe to *a notion of what's right*.

Comment: I don't know that I agree that "unburdened" etc. imply "being released from some obligation" (one that was there before and now isn't). The matching verbs ("to unburden" etc.) do mean that, but I wouldn't see anything wrong with saying that someone/something is "unburdened" by things that limit *others*, but have never applied *to them*.

Comment: "unfettered" is the word that came to my mind as well.

Answer (score 1):

**At leisure**

From MacMillan, [at leisure](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/at-leisure): *free to do what you want.*

Comment: Could you provide references? It will improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Elements of **Innocent**

1. a pure, guileless, or naive person.
   "a young innocent abroad"
2. a person involved by chance in a situation, especially a victim of crime or war.
   "they are prepared to kill or maim innocents in pursuit of a cause"

Answer (score 1):

**Supernumerary**

One definition is "Not wanted or needed; redundant".

For example (Cambridge dictionary, quoting Hansard) "The view is also held in certain places that there is a large number of supernumeraries in the administration who ought not to be there at all.

Comment: It's a fun word that I hadn't seen before, but I'm not sure it applies. From the examples I'm seeing, the supernumeraries still have responsibilities. They just collectively have fewer responsibilities than they could reasonably handle. So you could fire some of them and the job would still get done, but until you do they're still expected to perform their (small) share of the work.

Comment: I've certainly seen it used in precisely this sense, but it's possible it's localised, for example to the British Civil Service or armed forces. It may also have dropped out of use, I don't know.

Comment: Here's an example from 2019: https://www.nmc.org.uk/supporting-information-on-standards-for-student-supervision-and-assessment/student-empowerment/what-to-expect/supernumerary-protected-learning-time/

Answer (score 0):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sinecurist) gives:

**sinecurist** (noun): ***one who has a sinecure***

Where *sinecure* is:

**sinecure** (noun): ***an office or position that requires little or no work and that usually provides an income***

Comment: My question was more about the state of having no responsibility, not being in a position or state in which no responsibility is assigned.
No assignment of responsibility could lead to a state of no responsibility, but a sinecurist could also be a part time coal miner.

Answer (score 0):

#### Spare resources.

In a business context, employees and their time are resources. Often, businesses don't want 100% resource utilization, since that doesn't give any slack in case someone gets sick, goes on vacation, or is otherwise unavailable. As such, the employees who don't have any tasks currently assigned to them can be said to be spare resources.

Of course, this is a noun phrase, not an adjective that describes a noun. "Bob is sick today. What spare resources do we have?"

Answer (score 0):

**Not in charge.**

Person who isn't in charge for something ( responsible ) isn't irresponsible, but rather not assigned to the duty.

Comment: Typically this means "not in command". People not in charge still have responsibilities they're charged with. I'm struggling to come up with a sentence where being not in charge implies having no duties. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

**Drone**

Merriam Webster second definition [" one that lives on the labors of others : PARASITE"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drone)

Based on bees, the drones are male bees who do not gather nectar but are there purely to mate [Wikipedia Drone(bee)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drone_(bee))

As used by P G Wodehouse in the Jeeves and Wooster books to describe the wealthy young men who did not work but lived off inherited money.

For OP's second example - "His body finally able to rest, the industrial man becomes a drone"